# Django simple GROUP BY

Tags: django, django-models

I want to select one book per category and get count of books in each category

My model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

SQL should look something like:
`SELECT title, COUNT(*) as total FROM book GROUP BY category`

I've tried to use annotate method

`Book.objects.annotate(total_messages=Count('category'))`

But it grouped by book.id, so I got list of all books, not grouped at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) if you want to specify grouping fields:

```
Book.objects.values('category').annotate(total_messages=Count('title'))
```

Here's the query it produces:

```
>>> Book.objects.values('category').annotate(total_messages=Count('title')).query.__str__()
Out[11]: u'SELECT "my_app_book"."category", COUNT("my_app_book"."title") AS "total_messages" FROM "my_app_book" GROUP BY "my_app_book"."category"'
```

Comment: This does not return book.title and book.pk. Is there any way to add them?

Comment: Remember, you've asked for a query where the data is grouped by category. The query in the answer is the same as you were trying to get, isn't it?

Comment: FYI, for each category you will have multiple book titles and book ids.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Book.objects.values('category').annotate(total_messages=Count('title'))
```

Comment: This does not return book.title and book.pk. Is there any way to add them?

Comment: You need another query to do that. Another option is using Q object or raw query (not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

This means that the only way to achieve what you want in a single query, is to use an `OUTER JOIN` statement. The Django ORM does not support `OUTER JOIN` statements from a table to itself, as far as I know.

The only way to get what you want (a list of books with the count of the number of books in that book's category), apart from using a raw SQL statement, is to use 2 separate queries and process them in Python.

```
qs = Book.objects.values('category').annotate(count=Count('id'))
count = dict([(x['category'], x['count']) for x in qs])
books = Book.objects.all()
for book in books:
    book.category_count = count['category']
```